# Razor pages - EF entity/table relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, visual-studio-code, razor-pages

Can anybody point me to a simple explanation of how you define entity/table relationships using Entity Framework with Razor Pages?

EF is meant to make life easier: however, as I'm using Visual Studio Code, there seems to be no way to view any relationships it has stored and it's far from straightforward trying to add relationships when none of the examples shows how to do this using Razor Pages. I have entity models for each table, a database context and a statement on my main page loading data from the table. I want to add data from related entities but can't figure out where the entity relationships should be defined.

Any pointers?

Thanks.
[image]

Edit:

Thanks for the links. They look very helpful as far as clarifying the basic concept but most of my issues with Razor Pages have been about the mechanics - that is, what is defined where?

I've added a diagram to the question showing part of my table structure (all of the database tables already exist in MySQL and I can show entries from the *PC* table).

My data context (connecting to MySQL) is *Data\xContext.cs*. My current models for the tables here are *Holiday.cs, Location.cs* and *PC.cs* in the *Models* folder.

I show a table filtering on *OurLoc* matched to a *Location.ID* selected by the user, to show PCs only for the chosen location.

Do I create a new model in *Models* for each group of related tables/entities, or add the relationships to existing table models, or to the data context?

The models don't actually seem to be used in calls to view data (I renamed *PC.cs* as an experiment and still got the data.) Are they used only in scaffolding? I have the statement

```
public List<PC> PCList {get; set;} = new List<PC>();
```

on my page but don't understand where the definition of *`List<PC>()`* comes from if it isn't this model...

Comment: In EF relationships are modeled using Navigation Properties on the Entities.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Comment: Here's another attempt to explain navigational properties in EF Core (by me): https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships

Comment: If you use visualstudio there is an plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools that can make diagrams from the entites/DB Context

Comment: Thanks. These are great for clarifying the theory but my main problems are in knowing *where* to put everything - see my edit above. (It's got much more complicated since I added the View Component and I may try to see if I can get the app so far to work without that element.)

Comment: Thanks to Tan but I'm using Visual Studio Code, which doesn't seem to work with EF addons.

Comment: can you show us a part of the controller code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Razor Pages and don't understand what/where the controller code is. I've removed my View Component, which proved to be unnecessary and just complicated things. My major problem is where to declare the relationships - whether I can modify my existing table-based models, or should put the declarations in the context class. I have the statement _PCList = await (from p in db.PC join l in db.Location on p.LocationID equals l.ID where p.LocationID == OurLoc select p).ToListAsync();_ but can't access the contents of _l_ (el).